# How to disable UI multi touch in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Awake()
{
    Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;
}  

public void touch()
{
    Score++;
}
```

This doesn't work.

Touch multiple times at once to increase your score multiple times. Help me to increment once even with multiple presses.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore touches, when finger count is > 1.

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
{
     Score++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on how you detect the touch. With `multiTouchEnabled` set   to false, you might still get a `MouseDown` event or something similar for some other than the first finger. Nevertheless, after a press, you can *lock* the functionality of increasing your score until you know there is no touch and then *unlock* it again.

```cs
bool locked = false;

//call this whenever you detect a touch, no matter how
public void Touch() {
 if(!locked){
   locked = true;
   score++; 
 }

void Update(){
  if(Input.touchCount == 0) locked = false;
}
```